# return login user's score Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm making a simple quiz app which will return login user's result after they submit it. However, here returns all user's results instead of the login user only.

```
 <template name="personality">

<h1 class=personalityIntro>I see myself as someone who...</h1>
   <div class="test">

     {{> quickForm 
      collection="Big5"
      id="insertPersonality"
      type="method"
      meteormethod="submitBig5Scale"}}

  </div>

   <div class="userRe">
    <hr>
      {{#each big5s}}
         {{> showResult}}
      {{/each}}

    </div>
</template>
<template name="showResult">
   <div class=testResult>
      <h2>Neuroticism: {{>neurotic cons8}}</h2>
   </div>
</template>

<template name="showResult">
 <div class=testResult>
  <h2>Neuroticism: {{>neurotic cons8}}</h2>

</div>
</template>
```

This is how I store my data:

```
   Big5.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
       cons8: {
        label: "...is talkative",
        type: Number,
        optional: false,
        autoform: {
            afFormGroup: {
           type: "select-radio-inline",
          'formgroup-class': 'custom-radio-class',
          options: function () {
            return [
              {label: "1", value: 1},
              {label: "2", value: 2},
              {label: "3", value: 3},
              {label: "4", value: 4},
              {label: "5", value: 5}

            ];
          }
        }   
      }
     },
 })
)
```

Find all user data:

```
  big5s: function (){    
            return Big5.find()
          }
        })
```

Return login user's result only:

```
 Template.neurotic.helpers({
      add: function(cons8){
        return Meteor.user().big5s.cons8
      }
    })
```

Comment: If you need to use the parameter `cons8` you have to do it like this: `Meteor.user().big5s[cons8]` But still the return seems to be wrong at all.

Comment: where in the schema are you saving the data on a per user basis?

Comment: UserResult = new Mongo.Collection('user_result');

Answer (score 0):

when you store the response data, you're not associating it with the user who made that response. your schema does not have a field, e.g. userId, to store information about the user, thus associating a user with their response.

your helper:

```
Template.neurotic.helpers({
      add: function(cons8){
        return Meteor.user().big5s.cons8
      }
    })
```

... which i don't see being called, i think is an attempt to get your schema data off the user object. I don't see any code that puts that data on the user object, so i think you're confused about how this is supposed to work.

you could start by adding a userId to the schema, e.g.

```
Big5.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
       userId: {
         type: String
       },
       cons8: {
        label: "...is talkative",
```

Your meteor method, which you don't show, would also populate that along with the cons8 data.

you don't show any publish code, so i reckon you have autopublish enabled. that will be sufficient for the moment.

your find() would then look something like this:

```
return Big5.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
```

if i'm wrong, and you do somehow have that response data hooked up to the user object, you need to show a lot more code to help us understand what you're doing.